# Edit an object in mongodb over nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Im trying to learn some NodeJS. I am trying to edit a note app to be a box app. The finish purpose is to have an app where i can define some boxes and edit (edit it contents). Starting from https://github.com/FaztTech/nodejs-notes-app code i made some changes.

Edit the schema:

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const CajaSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    contenido: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    user: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

module.exports = model("Caja", CajaSchema);
```

Edit controller:

```
const notesCtrl = {};

// Models
const Caja = require("../models/Note");

notesCtrl.renderNoteForm = (req, res) => {
  res.render("notes/new-note");
};

notesCtrl.createNewNote = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, description, contenido } = req.body;
  const errors = [];
  if (!title) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please Write a Title." });
  }
  if (!description) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please Write a Description" });
  }
  if (!contenido) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please Write a contenido" });
  }
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render("notes/new-note", {
      errors,
      title,
      description,
    });
  } else {
    const newNote = new Caja({ title, description, contenido });
    newNote.user = req.user.id;
    await newNote.save();
    req.flash("success_msg", "Note Added Successfully");
    res.redirect("/notes");
  }
};

notesCtrl.renderNotes = async (req, res) => {
  const notes = await Caja.find({ user: req.user.id })
    .sort({ date: "desc" })
    .lean();
  res.render("notes/all-notes", { notes });
};

notesCtrl.renderEditForm = async (req, res) => {
  const note = await Caja.findById(req.params.id).lean();
  if (note.user != req.user.id) {
    req.flash("error_msg", "Not Authorized");
    return res.redirect("/notes");
  }
  res.render("notes/edit-note", { note });
};

notesCtrl.updateNote = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, description,  contenido } = req.body;
  await Caja.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { title, description, contenido });
  req.flash("success_msg", "Note Updated Successfully");
  res.redirect("/notes");
};

notesCtrl.deleteNote = async (req, res) => {
  await Caja.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
  req.flash("success_msg", "Note Deleted Successfully");
  res.redirect("/notes");
};

module.exports = notesCtrl;
```

edit-note.hbs:

```
{{#each errors}}
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  {{text}}
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
{{/each}}

<div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3>Edit Note</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form action="/notes/edit-note/{{note._id}}?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{note.title}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="description" class="form-control">{{note.description}}</textarea>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">

<div class="input-group flex-nowrap">

    {{#each note.contenido}}
  <div class="form-group">
    <p>{{@key}}</p>
          <textarea name="{{@key}}" class="form-control">{{this}}</textarea>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when i edit the note, the object "contenido" inside mongodb updates to null instead of the new value. What is wrong?

Comment: The problem is very likely in how `contenido` is sent to the server. Look for the `updateNote` as it called from the front-end. The way the server is saving that variable (i.e. `await Caja.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { title, description, contenido });`) looks good.

Comment: tryied sending contenido inside {contenido }  but i get syntax error

Comment: cant get why it updates title and description, but it cant handle the object conetnido part.

Comment: when you are submitting the form, you are not sending the "contenido" object, you are sending his *keys*

Comment: and is it posible to send and object?

Comment: if i take out the itineration part of the each contenido to a single note.contenido (equal ass title and description) i get the object changed into a string. how could i pass an object so it handles it as needed